# Application Insight Correlation in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, blazor-server-side

Is Application Insight working properly in Blazor server app? I have multiple application in .net core, all application logging data properly only I see an issue with BlazorServerApp. Sometimes, It will log page request sometimes it won't. Application Correlation also not working in BlazorServer app as describe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#example)

I tested 2 scenarios

Scenario 1) Working properly - **WebApp**>>WebAPI>>WebAPI>>DB

[image]

.Net Core WebApp and API are logging data properly and I can easily correlate Nested API Calls.

Scenario 2) Not logging data properly - **BlazorServerApp**>>WebAPI>>WebAPI>>DB

Not able to see my Blazor page (/Student). I can see only few blazor page requests (/Index and JavaScript file)

[image]

For all the applications, I used below code to configure application Insight

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    }
```

Is there any specific setting or code change required for blazor Application?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector library.

Blazor server side is SPA application it is why you can see only root request.
To track pages try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/66687175/2576452