# Azure Web App with Linux Logging not works

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

i try my first steps with Azure. I have upload a WebApp (Blazor WASM Serverhosted) on a Linux System. Now i want to see the logs. My application brokes on Azure on startup. Everything I have tried has not worked.

- The logstream shows nothing.
- The Monitoring/logs are disabled
- I activate in Monitoring/App Service Logs the File System and go to FTP Folder and i don't find a log-folder or something like this

I hope for help to fix my App or Configuration on Azure

Answer (score 0):

Still the issue can be available in [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28611) . You can achieve this by using below steps.

Steps provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66687175/15997690). And I am deployed in **Linux** app service

Now you can be able to view the logs in application insights

[image]

You can **add/modify** the custom logs as well by using the custom telemetry client.

Refer [here](https://github.com/IvanJosipovic/BlazorApplicationInsights) for detailed information