# How to debug live server app in Blazor 6.0

Tags: iis, signalr, blazor

**Short version:**
For a Blazor app running on a live IIS server (the production server for my old asp.net site), how can I debug: check the app's memory usage, check for unhandled errors, see status of live and disconnected circuits, etc.?

**Long version:**
I'm implementing a lot of Circuit management in my gaming page.  It includes timers to determine when a player has timed-out long enough to be pulled from a game and so on.

In testing a game, I have 10-20 users connected.  I'm hoping to scale up to about 200 live users.  For the most part, the games work as expected, but sometimes players crash.  I suspect that there's a server error (null reference to a non-existent user Circuit etc.)-- something to do with timeout values etc.

Comment: Application insights does that. Not sure I'd call it debug though, more like monitor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040671/azure-application-insights-for-server-side-blazor

Comment: Okay, I've now watched a few introductory videos to Application Insights, and it looks pretty sexy.  Thank you!